# Only allow ssh from 192.168.XXX.XXX

Tags: ssh, iptables

How can I only allow ssh access from the local network (192.168.X.X) and drop all requests from the internet? 
What is the best option? adding an `iptables` rule or modifying the `/etc/hosts.allow` ?

Comment: when it comes to security you want to have defense in depth - that way if there is an error in the config or implementation you are still protected. I would suggest adding a firewall rule, configuring tcpwrappers and modifying the SSH rule in sshd,conf. Yu can rerad more here https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/149800066154/ssh-security-and-usability-part-5

Comment: You may also want to consider adding fail2ban.

Comment: @SteveRobillard thanks for the link on the sshd config options. Do you know how to implement the same thing using iptables?

Comment: ufw is just a frontend to iptables.